# ambiguous reference to member datatask swift Xcode 8

Tags: swift, nsurl, xcode8

I just updated my Xcode and have been trying to learn more about it. This is my code for Collection View Cell. I'm trying to get data from URL but I've been annoyed with this error. I tried all the solutions in here but they have different function structure. Also other solutions didn't work.

```
import UIKit


class PersonCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var personImage : UIImageView!



    func ConfigureCell (imgURL : String)
{

}

    func DownloadImage ( url : NSURL)
{

}

    func GetDatafromURL (URL : NSURL , completion :   @escaping ((   _ data :     NSData? , _ response : URLResponse? ,  _ error : NSError?) -> Void))
{
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL) { (data ,  response , error) in     
            completion (data , response, error)     
            }.resume()   
}
}
```

the code that worked in the tutorial video is something like this

```
    func GetDatafromURL (URL : NSURL , completion : ((  data : NSData? , response : NSURLResponse? ,  error : NSError?) -> Void))
{


    NSURLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithURL( URL) { (data ,  response , error) in

        completion(data : data , responce : response, error : error)


        }.resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `NSURL` to a `URL` using `.absoluteURL`

```
guard let url = URL.absoluteURL else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    //
}.resume()
```

*UPDATE*

Your completion block has the wrong types. You're using `NSData` instead of `Data` and `NSError` instead of `Error`. Here's an example of what it should look like below.

```
func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)
{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error
        completion(data, response, error)
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Both of your solutions give me the same error that I cannot invoke " dataTask" with an argument of type '(with : URL,Data?,URLResponse>,Error?)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the latest reference.

[func dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func dataTask(with url: URL,
>      completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
> ```

In Swift 3, the completionHandler of `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` takes 3 arguments with types `Data?`, `URLResponse?` and `Error?`. So, your method's `completion`, which is of type `(NSData?,URLResponse?,NSError?) -> Void` cannot be applied.

And it takes `URL` as its first parameter.

(Thanks to vadian, he suggested all needed things here.)

So, your `GetDatafromURL` needs to be something like this:

```
func GetDatafromURL(url: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ data: Data?, _ response: URLResponse?,  _ error: Error?) -> Void))
{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion (data , response, error)
    }.resume()
}
```